# Get the ID from an Element in BIRT-Designer

Tags: javascript, birt

Can someone told me, how i get the value from an Element in BIRT-Report Designer?
I tried the follwing in a dynamic Text Element but it didn´t work

```
var e = reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(5514);

if(e > 13)
{
"bigger"
}
else
{
"smaller"
}
```

(5514) is the ID from a Data report Item.
It count a column in my dataset.

I also tried to get the value from this element by using:

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("myElementId")
```

But also not working

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in the onFetch event and in fact anywhere in BIRT is definitely possible, we are using it frequently.
Probably your DS does not return any data or an exception occurs.

Add logging statements to the beforeOpen and afterOpen events, that will tell you if the query is executing at all (and you're able to log the actual DS parameter values using this.getInputParamaeterValue("param_Foo").
Quite often, you find that a parameter is null or uses a default value because you forgot to set the DS parameter bindings in the layout.

If the beforeOpen event runs, but not afterOpen, then the DB doesn't like your query.
If the afterOpen event runs, but not the onFetch, then your query returned zero rows.
Also, run your report as HTML to see if there's a JavaScript error (shown in red at the end of the output).

Comment: Many thanks - the problem was in the onFetch() Method.